# Can a Flash SWF access Javascript when the files are on different servers? SwfAddress.js not working.

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, swfaddress

I had a somewhat weird setup for a site here, which goes as follows:

Server A holds a SWF
Server B holds a HTML document with the SWF Embedded, along with SwfAddress.js

I can't seem to get any Flash-to-javascript to work here through External Interface calls. SwfAddress fails and I see this error in Firebugs Console: "Error calling method on NPObject!"

This also occurs with another JS function I'm trying to call with the MouseWheel.

I've set up my crossdomains and deployed all Security.allowDomain("")'s where applicable.

Has anyone embedded an external SWF and had issues with AS-JS communication before??

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this thread? similar issue http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=137138